# How to make a scrollbar, slider bar, something like that (android)

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am not good at English. It's probably why I can't get the answer in Google. What I want is just an horizontal bar for selecting number in a range. But Google keeps showing me the scrollbar of view, layout etc.

Is there any tutorial? Am I searching with a wrong keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html). Here's some tutorials:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/SeekBar1.html
- http://forum.gssdaily.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=202